# Cannot make outlet in connected custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I've made a custom UITableViewCell Class, I've connected the class to the TableViewCell in the storyboard. It just showed up at the Custom Class menu, where I selected it.

But for some vague reason it doesn't show up in the Assistant Editor under Automatic, so I can't make IBOutlets. I've tried some guides, but they don't work (clean xcode, clean derivativeData, restart macbook).

How to fix this? I'm using xCode 7.2.1 and coding in Swift for iOS.

Comment: have you tried to: 1- Change the UITableViewCell class to your custom class inside the Storyboard? 2- Switch to the "manual" assistant editor and choose your custom UITableViewCell subclass?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

in the ViewControllerScene, if you select the cell, you will see the ViewController in the Assistant Editor, but if you select the Content View of the cell, you should see the ViewController and the Custom Cell in the Assistant.

Here's what I see when I select the Cell
[image: Select Cell]

and here's what I get when I select the Content View
[image: Content View]

Comment: I feel like a spoon for not noticing that xD. Thanks.

Comment: do we need a <spoon> emojii?

Comment: Another spoon here if it makes you feel better. Sigh.

Comment: saved time in the time of pandemics. :D

Comment: I created new project without knowing this and thought it is some kind of referencing issue, only to face the same error in the new project as well. Finally, I learnt what I missed. Thank you, @Russell